# AWS Tcp Server Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services

Today I registered aws free and transfered my server files to aws.
When I start it, It shows ip and port. that means the server is ready.

but when I tried to connect with client or telnet, All connections go to time out.

I think there must be a server configuration?
how can I solve it?

thanks

Comment: Can you paste your Security group rules for your EC2 instance and also which port you are using for the TCP?

Comment: where is it? port 10999

Comment: When You launched a EC2 instance you created a security group right?

Comment: Security Groups associated with i-006d4fb16e4a9145b
Ports Protocol Source launch-wizard-1
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔

Comment: Add a new Security rule Custom TCP - TCP - 10999 - 0.0.0.0/32 and it will work

Comment: now 
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
10999
0.0.0.0/32 but it doesn t work

Comment: Also add HTTP - TCP - 80 - 0.0.0.0/32 and then check

Comment: Sorry change the Custom TCP rule to Custom TCP - TCP - 10999 - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/32
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
10999
0.0.0.0/32 it doesnt work again

Comment: Remove that 32 and make them "0" sorry my mistake for both rules

Comment: no again 
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/32
SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
10999
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Remove this 32 also HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/32 and make it 0

Comment: no all of them 0 but nothing changes.

Comment: Credentials problem ?

Comment: Give me some details about your application what it is and on what Server it is set

Comment: it is python game server

Comment: I try to ping server but it is not alive

Comment: solved I tried to connect console ip 173.xx.xx.xx but i need to use public ip in the console